How do I make jigsaw blocks automatically run upon using structure blocks?
I am trying to look at every single chamber in the new trial chambers. Everything is generating, but there are a ton of jigsaw blocks. Some work when I use them, but some generate the wrong direction, or don't run at all (like the "turn into" ones).
How do I make them automatically run, and run the same way normal generation would? I also need the "turn into" ones to turn into the block it says automatically, how would I do that?
